# I want to filter array by grouping each two element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a big array and want to filter it by comparing each two elements.

for ex :

```
0:
id: "0.0.243"
key: {base: '1.3.0', quote: '1.3.1', sequence: -173}
op:
account_id: "1.2.71"
fee: {amount: 0, asset_id: '1.3.0'}
order_id: "1.7.475"
pays: {amount: 96000, asset_id: '1.3.1'}
receives: {amount: 96000000, asset_id: '1.3.0'}
time: "2022-10-11T13:42:24"

1:
id: "0.0.242"
key: {base: '1.3.0', quote: '1.3.1', sequence: -172}
op:
account_id: "1.2.460"
fee: {amount: 4800, asset_id: '1.3.1'}
order_id: "1.7.709"
pays: {amount: 96000000, asset_id: '1.3.0'}
receives: {amount: 96000, asset_id: '1.3.1'}
time: "2022-10-11T13:42:24"
```

so here I need to compare each two elements by it's order_id,

like :  `1.7.709 > 1.7.475`

I'm trying like this :

```js
const trial = histories.filter((history, i, arr) => { 
         const prev = arr[i - 1];
         return history.op.order_id === prev.op.order_id;
         });
       console.log(trial);
```

but it doesn't work.
how can I achieve my expected result?

here is array looks like

[image]

I want to filter array by higher order id but have two compare each two elements , like need to check with order id is higher between index 0 and index 1.

Comment: So, what do you want to do, after comparing them? Do you want to reoder the elements?

Comment: The _"ex"_ is invalid syntax. The snippet doesn't do anything useful and therefor should be a code-block or add the relevant input and make it an actual [mcve]. _"it doesn't work"_ isn't a useful problem description. And please don't post images of relevant code, errors, ... (or unrelated stuff) -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For me is not clear what do you want to achieve... do you want to filter? group? order?

Comment: Can you please show the example of "grouping" you mentioned in the question title?

Comment: Don't post images of code, and certainly not console output. Take the time to clearly type or paste your input and expected output as text in syntax valid for the language being asked about, and show your attempt, ideally as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I want to filter array by higher order id but have two compare each two elements , like need to check with order id is higher between index 0 and index 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a standard `for` loop you can just iterate every 2. This logic can be moved to a `reduce()` if you prefer.

```js
const histories = [
  {
    id: "0.0.243",
    op: { order_id: "1.7.475", }
  },
  {
    id: "0.0.242",
    op: { order_id: "1.7.709", }
  },
  {
    id: "0.0.241",
    op: { order_id: "1.7.475", }
  },
  {
    id: "0.0.240",
    op: { order_id: "1.7.708", }
  }
];

const result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < histories.length; i += 2) {
  result.push(
    histories[i].op.order_id >= histories[i + 1].op.order_id
      ? histories[i]
      : histories[i + 1]
  );
}

console.log(result);
```

Using `reduce()`

```js
const histories = [{ id: "0.0.243", op: { order_id: "1.7.475", } }, { id: "0.0.242", op: { order_id: "1.7.709", } }, { id: "0.0.241", op: { order_id: "1.7.475", } }, { id: "0.0.240", op: { order_id: "1.7.708", } }];

const result = histories.reduce((acc, curr, i, { [i - 1]: next }) => {
  if (i % 2) {
    acc.push(curr.op.order_id >= next.op.order_id ? curr : next)
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure which item you want to filter out among the two elements, but judging by your needs I suggest you to use `arr.reduce()`.

Comment: I want to filter array by higher order id but have two compare each two elements , like need to check with order id is higher between index 0 and index 1.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but is it that you want to shorten the list of arrays from 16 to 8 in length, for example ?